# How to match statistics from two dictionaries and group by key in new dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
this_week = [
        {
          "Stat": {
            "clicks": "1822",
            "affiliate_id": "1568",
            "advertiser_id": "1892",
            "offer_id": "2423847"
          },
          "Offer": {
            "name": "app2"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "clicks": "11",
            "affiliate_id": "1616",
            "advertiser_id": "2171",
            "offer_id": "2402467"
          },
          "Offer": {
            "name": "two"
          }
        }
]
```

and

```
last_week = [
        {
          "Stat": {
            "clicks": "1977",
            "affiliate_id": "1796",
            "advertiser_id": "1892",
            "offer_id": "2423847"
          },
          "Offer": {
            "name": "app2"
          }
        },
        {
          "Stat": {
            "clicks": "1248",
            "affiliate_id": "1781",
            "advertiser_id": "2171",
            "offer_id": "2402467"
          },
          "Offer": {
            "name": "two"
          }
        }
]
```

I want to make a dictionary like

```
 items = {"1892" (advertiser_id):
            {'this_week':
                  {
                       {
                           "Stat": {
                           "clicks": "1822",
                           "affiliate_id": "1568",
                           "advertiser_id": "1892",
                           "offer_id": "2423847"
                       },
                           "Offer": {
                                "name": "app2"
                       } 
        },
    },
            {'last_week':
                  {
                       "Stat": {
                             "clicks": "1977",
                             "affiliate_id": "1796",
                             "advertiser_id": "1892",
                             "offer_id": "2423847"
                        },
                        "Offer": {
                              "name": "app2"
                        }
            },
            {'difference': 
                  { "clicks_difference": this_week['1892']['Stat']['clicks'] - last_week['1892']['Stat']['clicks'] }
         }
```

for given advertiser_id, offer_id or affiliate_id depending on user's choice. And here is the problem. The order of items in both dictionaries may not be the same, so is there any other way to group these parameters by advertiser_id or any other key?

How to group these data this way if we can change the grouping id? What is the shortest way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean under `'advertiser_id' (or 'affiliate_id' or 'offer_id')`? Grouping if any of the fields match? And if that's the case, what should be the key for that dictionary? And how do you determine which one is `this_week` and which one is `last_week`? And can two of those groupings ever repeat (if they can you need to hold them in a list), and... So many things left unclear from the question...

Comment: @zwer - for example, for advertiser_id. I meant that the solution should be universal in the case if we change the advertiser_id to any other key.

Comment: @zwer according groupings, these two dictionaries are the results of the request to the API, where we choose by which attribute to slice data in statistics. It means that fields may disappear from the response, if we didn't mention advertiser_id in the request, but mentioned only offer_id, we'll see only offer_id in the response.

Comment: And what would constitute a `difference`?

Comment: Can you give the exact dictionary you would like as output instead of "... data from the first dictionary ..." and "X or Y". Be specific.

Comment: @JonasAdler done.

Comment: @zwer I added more details to the main topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten one list into a map and then loop & match with the other list on a set field, and finally calculate the click difference if you have both lists, something like:

```
def join_on(this, last, field):
    # first turn the first list into a [field_value] => [matched_stat] map:
    result = {stat["Stat"].get(field, None): {"this_week": stat} for stat in this}
    for stat in last:  # loop through the second list
        field_value = stat["Stat"].get(field, None)  # get the value of the selected field
        if field_value in result:  # check if it was already parsed in the `this` list
            result[field_value]["last_week"] = stat  # store it as last week
            # get the click value for this week:
            clicks = int(result[field_value]["this_week"]["Stat"].get("clicks", 0))
            clicks -= int(stat["Stat"].get("clicks", 0))  # subtract the last week clicks
            # store the click difference in the `difference` key
            result[field_value]["difference"] = {"clicks_difference": clicks}
        else:  # no field found in the `this` list, store it just as last week and continue..
            result[field_value]["last_week"] = stat
    return result
```

Then you can check it with your data as:

```
parsed_data = join_on(this_week, last_week, "advertiser_id"))
```

Which gives:

```
{'1892': {'difference': {'clicks_difference': -155},
          'last_week': {'Offer': {'name': 'app2'},
                        'Stat': {'advertiser_id': '1892',
                                 'affiliate_id': '1796',
                                 'clicks': '1977',
                                 'offer_id': '2423847'}},
          'this_week': {'Offer': {'name': 'app2'},
                        'Stat': {'advertiser_id': '1892',
                                 'affiliate_id': '1568',
                                 'clicks': '1822',
                                 'offer_id': '2423847'}}},
 '2171': {'difference': {'clicks_difference': -1237},
          'last_week': {'Offer': {'name': 'two'},
                        'Stat': {'advertiser_id': '2171',
                                 'affiliate_id': '1781',
                                 'clicks': '1248',
                                 'offer_id': '2402467'}},
          'this_week': {'Offer': {'name': 'two'},
                        'Stat': {'advertiser_id': '2171',
                                 'affiliate_id': '1616',
                                 'clicks': '11',
                                 'offer_id': '2402467'}}}}
```